# Which of the two versions of `>&` are used for `[n]>&/dev/tcp/localhost/9999`?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I'm not sure whether to interpret `/dev/tcp/localhost/9999` as an integer (file descriptor) or as a filename.

Consequently, I'm not sure whether the "**Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error**" (1) or the "**Duplicating File Descriptors**" (2) section of the Bash manual applies to the redirection above.

The redirection works both if `n` is specified or not, but (1) doesn't take an `n` argument, implying that (1) is not used?

Furthermore, if `/dev/tcp/localhost/9999` is considered a filename (not an integer), why do the `<&1` in the following command works?:

```
/bin/bash >&/dev/tcp/localhost/9999 <&1
```

In this case, `1` (stdout) is not a file descriptor open for input making (2) fail?

Comment: @mosvy, are file descriptors in Bash, incl. stdin, stdout, and stderr always read/write? Also, on the command line, does Bash see `/dev/tcp/...` as a filename or as the underlying file descriptor's "digits"? Some redirection depends on this distinction.

Comment: `/dev/tcp/../..` neither a filename nor a file descriptor. It's a special case. At syntax level, it will act as a path (`>&/dev/tcp/../..` will be intepreted as the deprecated "redirect stdout+err", not as "dup fd").

Comment: @mosvy, thank you very much for this clarification. Would you also comment on, whether file descriptors in Bash are generally opened read/write, including stdin, stdout, and stderr?

Comment: "generally", in a interactive shell running in a terminal, stdin/out/err are all dupes of the same file referring to the terminal, which is opened in read/write mode. `> file` will open `file` only for writing, etc. The `>/dev/tcp/../..` hack is a confusing exception (where it doesn't matter if its `>`, `<` or `<>`).

Comment: @mosvy, by "same file", do you mean `/dev/tty` (device file representing the terminal)?

Comment: @mosvy, also, if I understand it correctly, in my command above, it doesn't matter whether `>&` or `&>` is used, since both redirect stdout/stderr, which is how the command is interpreted by Bash at a syntactical level?

Comment: Not exactly. The way it goes is like this: file descriptor -> file ("open file descrip**tion**") -> inode -> device. Opening `/dev/tty` will get you a fd which refers to the controlling terminal, which may be the same as that fds 0, 1 and 2 refer to, but through a different file and inode.

Comment: `>& path` and `&> path` are the same thing in bash (and they're both __deprecated__): `foo(){ cmd >& file; }; typeset -fp foo` => will print the `>&` as `&>`.

Comment: @mosvy, thanks again. In my Bash, only `>& path` is reported as deprecated in the man pages. Why do you bold "tion" in your comment above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dev/tcp/host/port` will always be opened read-write, no matter if you use `<`, `>` or `<>` (and `>&` or `&>` in `bash`).

`>& /dev/tcp/host/port` will connect to `host:port` and redirect both the stdout and the stderr to it.

The `/dev/tcp` hack uses `socket(2)` and `connect(2)` behind the scenes and there's no obvious and consistent way to use a tcp socket as if it were a file descriptor open only for read or write.

And a file descriptor simply being number 1 and calling itself stdout doesn't mean it's not open for input: `cat <&1` also works in the terminal.

> The redirection works both if n is specified or not, but (1) doesn't take an n argument, implying that (1) is not used?

Not here.

```
true 3>&/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/9999
bash: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/9999: ambiguous redirect
```

Comment: A uni-directional tcp connection can be created in a straightforward way by shutting down the direction you don't want (with `shutdown(2)`)

Comment: That will open a can of worms (eg. the other end will close the connection).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas and `shutdown(2)` will not reflect in the file modes; a `fcntl(F_GETFL)` on the socket fd will still show it as `O_RDWR`.

Comment: Yes, I'm not saying shells should do it (though I'm not convinced it would cause significant problems, it would also not be particularly useful). I was just objecting to your *there's no obvious and consistent way of create a uni-directional tcp connection*. Note that ksh93 does use  (unix domain) SOCK_STREAM socket pairs for its pipes on Linux, and does shutdown the reverse direction.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That's completely different, since ksh93 controls both ends. Otherwise, a simple `cat </dev/tcp/../..` to print a server banner could fail. Also notice that trying to write to a socket fd after `shutdown(SHUT_WR)` behaves differently than writing to a file open in read-only mode (it should result in a `SIGPIPE` signal). All this is neither obvious nor consistent IMHO.