# /dev/tcp/host/port, /dev/udp/host/port what kernel module is this?

Tags: debian, drivers, tcp, udp

I noticed this in the bash(1) man page.  Is there an operating system or certain kernel module that provides this interface?  Tried it on my Debian installation and these devices do not exist.

Thanks

```
      /dev/tcp/host/port
             If host is a valid hostname or Internet address, and port is an integer  port  number  or  service
             name, bash attempts to open the corresponding TCP socket.
      /dev/udp/host/port
             If  host  is  a  valid hostname or Internet address, and port is an integer port number or service
             name, bash attempts to open the corresponding UDP socket.
```

SOLUTION/ANSWER:
This works and it is a feature of the shell.  To test:

```
$ nc -l -p 5555

echo Hello > /dev/tcp/localhost/5555

$ nc -l -p 5555
Hello
```

Very cool.

Comment: If it's in the bash man page, why can't it be a bash feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Jeff says, this is a feature [implemented by Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html), not by the kernel. It’s only available to shell scripts or on the shell’s command line; other programs can’t open `/dev/tcp/...`.

To implement this as a kernel module you’d have to provide a new virtual file system.

To see this in action, you can combine Bash with netcat. Run

```
nc -l -p 5555
```

in one terminal, then

```
echo Hello > /dev/tcp/localhost/5555
```

in another; you’ll see “Hello” in the terminal running `nc`.

Comment: Did certain versions of Bash implement this or have a method of enabling?  So far, my version on Debian does not have this enabled by default.

Comment: @Nick Of course Debian's *bash* has this feature, be sure to be using *bash* and not *dash* (which could be *sh*'s alias). To check it, install strace and do: `strace -f bash -c 'echo > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/5555' 2>&1 |egrep 'socket|connect'`

Comment: A.B cat < /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/5555 
-bash: connect: Connection refused
-bash: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/5555: Connection refused ---- Thanks.  Do you know how to get a bidirectional socket running.  Interested in using this feature!  Thanks

Comment: @A.B It [doesn't matter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538461/308316) a bit if you're using `<>`, `<` or `>` with the `/dev/tcp/` hack. Try it yourself: `{ echo helo nasty >&0; cat; } </dev/tcp/smtp.gmail.com/submission`

Comment: @mosvy yes you are right.

Comment: The Debian bash used to have this feature disabled.

Comment: For this example I get a connection refused.  I think this question is mostly answered, but I'd like to see the socket in action for myself... I'm using Debian 4.9.130

Comment: @Nick try with `nc -l -p 5555`. Unfortunately, there a many versions of `nc`, one more broken than the other. Nmap's version (`apt-get install ncat`) is a bit more usable.

Comment: @mosvy that’s interesting, thanks; I’d understood from the docs that `-p` specifies the source port (including with the Nmap version), but that’s not accurate apparently, and it’s really the port `nc` binds to, regardless of direction... (The “(doesn't affect -l)” mention on `-s` in the Nmap `nc` manpage does give a hint though.)

Comment: @mosvy It worked